# Extend a class with private constructer

Tags: java, constructor, private, extends

Is it possible to extend a class with a nonvisible constructor without having to know what this constructor do and implement it again?

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
    
public class myDriverManager extends DriverManager {
    public myDriverManager() {
        super(); //Fehler: the constructor DriverManager() ist not visible
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is because the constructor in `DriverManager` is private
`/* Prevent the DriverManager class from being instantiated. */`
`private DriverManager(){}`

Comment: If you were intended to extend that class, the author of that class would have made the constructor protected or public. As it is, you can't extend it.

Comment: Is `DriverManager` just an example here or do you really want to extend that class? What is the reason for that? From Javadocs: "NOTE: The DataSource interface, new in the JDBC 2.0 API, provides another way to connect to a data source. The use of a DataSource object is the preferred means of connecting to a data source." - version 2.0 has been out for quite a while now.

Comment: DriverManager became just an example, because I actually tried it with it, but made progress and exited to even don't want to extend it^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't extend [DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html), but you can implement `DataSource` instead

> NOTE: The DataSource interface, new in the JDBC 2.0 API, provides another way to connect to a data source. The use of a DataSource object is the preferred means of connecting to a data source.

Answer (score 2):

Every constructor's first line is either a call to its super class constructor or to any current class constructor, so even if you don't keep it compiler will keep a `super();` as first line.

Now coming to `DriverManager` its only constructor is `private` and when you extend it to your class, its constructor will try to call the `DriverManager`'s constructor as per above logic and gives Compile time error since its private and becomes not visible.

The case will be same even if you don't declare the class without constructor

```
public class myDriverManager extends DriverManager {
    
}
```

This will also give the same error, because the compiler will create a default constructor and its first line will be `super();` by default, again by the above logic, constructor is again invisible.

So basically what happens is when you extend `DriverManager` your class has to call `super();` at some part of its code, and gives compile time error and hence `DriverManager` cannot be extended to any class.